# C# create child events from a parent event

Tags: c#, events

I have a list of events (e.g. List) that have a start and end date, some events can be weekly events (IsWeekly). I need to create a list of weekly events from a single event. E.g.

myEvent starts 19/04/2011 ends 10/05/2011 (this is a single event in my database)

i need an output like:

myEvent 19/04/2011

myEvent 26/04/2011

myEvent 03/05/2011

myEvent 10/05/2011

The above 4 events need to be added to my List and the original 'parent' event removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var current = startDate;
do {
  list.Add(new MyEvent("My Event", current));
  current = current.AddDays(7);
} while (current < endDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I've understood your question correctly, but I think you need to define your delegate type, and then define an event:

```
delegate void YourDelegate(DateTime d);
event YourDelegate YourEvent = null;
```

and then call it when need be:

```
if (YourEvent != null) YourEvent(DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a lookup table, that has two columns that are keys to the events, and have a ParentEvent|ChildEvent layout, so if your 'parent' has 3 children, his key is listed 3 times, tied to different children keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<DateTime> GetEvents(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    List<DateTime> events = new List<DateTime>();

    DateTime e = start;
    while(e <= end)
    {
         e = e.AddDays(7);
         events.Add(e);
    }

    return events;
}
```